# Dell optiplex turns on no display signal fan very noisy

Tags: boot, desktop, fan

I was working as usual on my Dell OptiPlex 7010 MT today and then suddenly the machine became unresponsive. I forced a shut down and then tried to turn it on again and then the power on button is usually white on successful boot but now it's yellow and then the hard drive light is flashing on and off. The hard drive is plugged in and working. I get no display on the monitor and the PSU fan is producing an unpleasant noise.

What could be the problem? I have tried removing the RAM, hard drive and other USB devices with no success.

I have also tried removing the video card and it still shows nothing when I connect to the other onboard video port.

The diagnostic power on led blinks three times and then two times, could it be a memory failure test?

Answer (score 0):

Our helpful friends over at Dell have provided us with a [reference guide to the Dell OptiPlex Diagnostic Indicators](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-uk/000126021/a-reference-guide-to-the-dell-optiplex-diagnostic-indicators?lwp=rt).

If the light is amber, and it blinks twice followed by a short pause, and then 3 times followed by a long pause and then repeats it means:

Bad Motherboard, Memory, or Processor

The advice they give for this situation is:

- If you can troubleshoot, narrow down the issue by reseating the memory and swapping a known working memory module, if available.
- If nothing works, replace the motherboard, memory, or processor.

Comment: Yes it is two beeps and then three beeps in amber

Comment: So that means its the RAM that has a problem, i have tried reseating ,unplugging but nothing works

Comment: it could be the motherboard, RAM, or processor. Try removing dust. Try replacing the RAM with a module that you know works (if you have one available).

Comment: I also suspect its dust, the motherboard works because am able to see the lights....

Comment: How do i remove dust?

Comment: Google "canned air" / "compressed air"

Comment: you can search for "remove dust from pc" on youtube

Comment: The motherboard is dead, the ram.slots got killed by the over clocked video card, its junk man

Comment: @CoderTimothy My condolences. That sucks bro.